# Unknown error in AJAX using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've tried for the last few hours to get this snippet of code working, it's supposed to load the div with the class content and replace the current pages .content via ajax. This is for a dynamic website, so I need it working on all non-outbound links.

```
$("a:not([href^='http://']), a[href^='http://www.example.com'], a[href^='http://example.com']").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var addressValue = $(this).attr("href");
    page = addressValue.replace(/https?:\/\/[^\/]+/i, "");
    pagecontent = page+" .content";
    $( ".content" ).load( pagecontent );
    $.ajax({
        url: page,
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
            var matches = data.match(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/);
        var spUrlTitle = matches[1];
                document.title = spUrlTitle;
        },
    });
});
```

I've systematically narrowed down the error to the following snippet of code. (everything beforehand works without it)

```
        pagecontent = page+" .content";
        $( ".content" ).load( pagecontent );
        $.ajax({
            url: page,
            async: true,
            success: function(data) {
                var matches = data.match(/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/);
            var spUrlTitle = matches[1];
                    document.title = spUrlTitle;
            },
        });
```

From further analysis, I have determined that the error is caused when clicking a link that has no http://

```
page = addressValue.replace(/https?:\/\/[^\/]+/i, "");
```

The above line of code cannot run as there is no http://

I'm unsure how I am going to fix this, but at least I've narrowed it down.

Comment: And what is the problem? Does the request go to the right url? Try adding an error handler and log the error if any.

Comment: your selector is wrong!

Comment: The error is that nothing happens, the link follows through as normal.

Please explain how my selector is wrong. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
page = addressValue.replace(/(https?:\/\/)?[^\/]+/i, "");
```

It basically says to remove `http://` or `https://` if it's at the front, but to keep parsing if there isn't a match.

Or, you could simply use the properties of the DOM anchor object that are already defined in the spec:

```
var link_Element =  $( this ).get( 0 );
page = link_Element.pathname + link_Element.search;
```

The above will concatenate the URL path after the hostname (and any other host-level info, like the port number, etc) with the URL query string, which are the only bits you would need for a local ajax request, so that :

```
 <a href="http://example.org/path/to/content">Full URL</a>
 <a href="/path/to/content">Local URL</a>
 <a href="/path/to/content?stuff=junk">Local URL with query string</a>
```

Would return:

```
 /path/to/content
 /path/to/content
 /path/to/content?stuff=junk
```

without having to do any string parsing/sanitizing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use this to reach pages outside your domain you will be blocked by sites that prevents cross-origin requests.. instead you can use

```
$.get(page, {/*params*/}, function(data) {
/*Success Callback*/
});
```

Comment: This is strictly for onsite links. :)

Comment: I think i misunderstood the question.. sorry

Comment: Have you considered returning false at the end of the event handler?

Comment: Yes, I have indeed. I'm going to quickly update the question with what I've narrowed the error down to.